# How to get service state on spring cloud contract stub

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-cloud, stubbing

Studying spring cloud contract have a question about testing statefull services.

Have two services: **Server** and **Client**. 
**Server** has a state, in my case it has repository with users. I can test **Server** states with spring cloud contract using [scenarios](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/).

My second step is using **Server-stub** for **Client** testing. In this case I'd like to have  **Server-stub** with one (or more) users. I can make this contract (just imagine Service always has users), but it will be another one.

What is the way to use the same contract to verify **Server** answers (firstly Server has zero state) and stubbing it while **Client** tests(when I need stub with some state)?

**UPD** Closer to my case: My **Server** contains users, which can be created/updated without participation of **Client**. For component testing **Server** I created contract scenario "Create user". Than I'd like to test **Client**, but it need **Server** to contain at least one user, i.e. got some special state on **Server-stub**. What shall I do in this case?

1. Have a different contracts to test **Server** and **Client**. In this case, how can I verify, that my client-contract is true.
2. Some how play a scenario or put **Server-stub** in state having one user.

PS tried to add tag spring-cloud-contract, by rating is not enough.

Comment: Hi! It's awesome to have the first ever Spring Cloud Contract question :) I don't know if I fully get your question but in Spring CLoud Contract Verifier we do support scenarios too - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_scenarios. But in general I'd suggest to have a couple of contracts in order not to do stateful tests. Can you elaborate more on the business use-case? That way we could think about how to solve this.

Comment: tried to update my question :) hope It helps you to get my case.

Comment: I think you'd have to write a BDD style scenario so that I fully get that. You could sketch the contracts too. Anyways let me try to help you somehow (assuming that I understood the problem). I understand that when testing the Server side you're not really relying on the DB content? You should mock it. Then you can separate scenarios - server has a user, server has no users. From there, on the client side, you can test 2 cases. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, I see. The answer is in mocking DB and the problem is I tried to use embed DB (flapdoodle for mongo), that is empty.

Comment: As I understand, the idea is to mock DB, that have user I need instead of using embed mongo. Or initiate it with some users @Before test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes so the answer to this problem is the fact that when having a controller you should delegate all the work to a service. That service should be mocked. Spring Cloud Contract is about contract tests, not exact replication of business features. You can read more about this sourish in the excellent blog entry from Stephane Nicoll https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4

Comment: Really, it would be great idea to add possibility using different base classes for different contracts.

Comment: That's true - we have it as an issue in our backlog - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/16 . You can vote for this issue ;)

Comment: The feature has been implemented @mhtyn! https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_different_base_classes_for_contracts Check out 1.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: great, I like it)